# How can i access a variable from a file in the public folder in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I ask a user: What is your username with a window.prompt

```
//public/js/Chat.js
username = window.prompt('What is your username?)
```

and in my root folder

```
//app.js
let chatMessage = new Chat({ message: msg, sender: username });
```

but of course that doesn't work because its not in the same file

So to counter that i tried this:

```
//public/js/Chat.js
export let username = window.prompt('What is your username?')
```

```
//app.js
import { username } from './public/js/Chat.js'
```

But that doesn't work because it's not a module.

Comment: Your comment says Node.js  but the prompt is obviously client side is the app.js script server side?

Comment: you need to use AJAX to send variables from client to server.

Comment: What web server are you running in your backend code? Express?

Comment: If you want to send both to the client, make sure to add ```"type": "module"``` to package.json to use the module. Else, you should look at a backend at an API connecting them.

Comment: To sum up some of these comments, it sounds like you have a backend and a frontend. Both are written in Javascript, but they unfortunately can't just import each other and share information. To do that, you might need to write a little API and send HTTP requests to your server.

Answer (score -1):

Add `"type": "module"` into package.json to use the above code as a module.